# How to apply advanced filter and keep one column unfiltered?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet of the following format:

```
Email Breach1 Breach2 Breach3... Breach13
```

I need to filter it down to only users affected by certain breaches (spread across all breach columns and repeated too). So I made a criteria like:

```
A         B          C            D               N 
1  email     Breach1   Breach2      Breach3   ...           Breach13    
2  email        2   
3  email                        Creative
4  email                        Linux Forums
15520 email                                         Exactis
                                               Linux Forums
```

The search pattern has both `AND` and `OR` like this:

```
Breach1 in ColumnA AND Breach2 OR Breach3 in ColumnB AND Breach2 OR Breach4 in ColumnC
```

and so on. I actually have the pattern in the sample file but I didn't figure out how to attach it. The first column is the emails - I don't want to touch it. I only want to filter through the breach names. So in my search criteria I used a new line for every OR, and I had only two names on the same line for AND.

[image: My sheet]

My problem is when I try the advanced filter it simply copies all the same values to a different location (I choose it) without filtering the names. When I try a criteria only on one column it works. But is it when I add all the 13 columns and want them to be filtered too? I guess I can do each column separately, but filtering though all columns at once would be more efficient if I knew the way.

Comment: My sheet range is A1:N15520.

Comment: "I want all the users that match the with the Breaches."  <---- I didn't get this part. I'm guessing that its = OR relation or AND relation. Mind posting some sample data/output/file to clarify?

Comment: Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1350031/edit) your question with additional information, rather than using comments

Comment: [object Object]Actually the pattern has both AND and OR: Breach1in ColumnA AND Breach2 in ColumnA AND Breach3 OR Breach4 in COLUMN4.

Comment: May not be a useful comment but I'd go for VBA here

Comment: Please post desired solution too, that might help to understand your problem.

Comment: Filtering only hides what you don't want to see, it doesn't actually change the data.  Your description is too ambiguous to know exactly what you're doing and what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Advanced Filter works. It might not give me what I want, but it does its job: it finds every row where one of those names exists. I was being thrown off by a large number of results.

Comment: Please only post an answer if it actually solves your issue. If you want to post additional information then simply edit your question.